# InDesign Missing Links

Tags: adobe-indesign

I have an InDesign file that I received from a client, when I open the file from a package I am told that links are missing. In comparing the "missing link" location and the "modified/fixed" link locations the location is exactly the same, but InDesign no longer thinks the link is missing. Does anyone have any ideas as to why this could happen?

Comment: Are the missing files in the packaged folder and are just not linked to the InDesign file or are the missing files not there at all?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a fluke to me, and hopefully fairly easy to relink the missing files, so I wouldn't worry about it too much.  What's really odd about this, however, is that you shouldn't be getting the "modified/fixed" error message either assuming you haven't moved the InDesign file out of the folder that also contains the "Links" folder.

But, if I had to guess, I would lay odds that this is what happened.  Whoever put together the original InDesign document packaged it, and then started changing the files in the packaged Links folder. Maybe they decided to replace a bunch of images with higher resolution versions before they sent them to you.  If the name of the higher resolution image was the same as the one that was originally created by packaging, InDesign will show you that the link was modified.  For the images that show up as "missing," maybe the original user decided to change the name of the images in the links file so that you would be able to better identify each of the images by their file name.  If so, InDesign is going to show that those images are missing.

You might be able to get a hint about what happened by opening the "Link Info" drop down in your links panel.  Take a look at the path that is shown at the bottom of this panel, and see what it shows for the original path and/or the original name of the missing linked file.  That may well give you the clue to figure out what happened.

Answer (score 0):

I created a video with 5 different methods for fixing broken links. I actually found 3+ methods that actually work when the original document isn't available. The other 2 methods may work if you have the Windows version of Indesign:

https://youtu.be/P8wPLywjXmo

Comment: Welcome to GDSE! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Feel free to browse the site, ask more question, upvote quality content and maybe leave an answer of your own.